# Recording video with iOS broadcasting extension

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, avassetwriter

I'm trying to tweak the iOS broadcasting extension feature to record the video instead of live streaming.
It seems possible because you can get pixel buffer in `processSampleBuffer:withType:` method.

Then I have coded like below but it fails when appending the buffer.

I'm familiar neither to AVAssetWriter nor App Extension programming so I cannot figure out what's wrong here.

Am I doing something we're not supposed to do in the extension? Or the usage of AVAssetWriter is wrong?

Any idea is helpful. Thanks!

```
//
//  SampleHandler.m
//  The main class of the App Extension
//
#import "SampleHandler.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation SampleHandler {
    VideoExporter *exporter;
    NSDate *startDate;
}

- (void)broadcastStartedWithSetupInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,NSObject *> *)setupInfo {
    // User has requested to start the broadcast. Setup info from the UI extension can be supplied but optional.
    [self setupWriter];    
}

- (void)setupWriter {
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Set video path into shared container
    NSURL *containerURL = [fm containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.mycompany"];
    NSURL *libraryURL = [containerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library" isDirectory: true];
    BOOL isDir = false;
    NSURL *cachesURL = [libraryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches" isDirectory: true];    
    NSURL *outVideoURL = [cachesURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[outVideoURL path]]){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[outVideoURL path] error:nil];
    }

    exporter = [[VideoExporter alloc] initWithOutputURL:outVideoURL size:CGSizeMake(1280, 720) frameRate:30];
    exporter.delegate = self;
    [exporter beginExport];

    startDate = [NSDate date];
}

- (void)broadcastPaused {
    // User has requested to pause the broadcast. Samples will stop being delivered.
}

- (void)broadcastResumed {
    // User has requested to resume the broadcast. Samples delivery will resume.
}

- (void)broadcastFinished {
    // User has requested to finish the broadcast.
    NSLog(@"User requested finish writing");
    [exporter finishWriting];
}

- (void)processSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer withType:(RPSampleBufferType)sampleBufferType {

    switch (sampleBufferType) {
        case RPSampleBufferTypeVideo:
            // Handle video sample buffer
            [exporter addCMSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
            break;
        case RPSampleBufferTypeAudioApp:
            // Handle audio sample buffer for app audio
            break;
        case RPSampleBufferTypeAudioMic:
            // Handle audio sample buffer for mic audio
            break;            
        default:
            break;
    }
}
@end


//
//  VideoExporter.m
//  Helper class to write the video
//
#import "VideoExporter.h"

@implementation VideoExporter

@synthesize width, height;
@synthesize framesPerSecond;
@synthesize outputURL;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithOutputURL:(NSURL *)aURL size:(CGSize)size frameRate:(uint64_t)fps {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        width = (int)round(size.width);
        height = (int)round(size.height);
        framesPerSecond = fps;
        outputURL = aURL;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)beginExport {    
    NSError *error = nil;
    writer = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:outputURL
                                       fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                          error:&error];
    NSAssert(writer != nil, @"Writer should not be nil");

    NSDictionary * outSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecTypeH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:height], AVVideoHeightKey, nil];
    writerInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput alloc] initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:outSettings];

    NSDictionary * pixelAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
    adaptor = [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor alloc] initWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:pixelAttributes];

    [writer addInput:writerInput];

    BOOL started = [writer startWriting];
    NSAssert(started, @"Should start writing!");

    [writer startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
}

- (void)addCMSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)buf {
    if(writer.status==0) {
        NSLog(@"Writer status unknown!!");
    }    
    [self appendCMSampleBuffer:buf];
}

- (void)finishWriting {        
    [writerInput markAsFinished];
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    int64_t longDuration = 1000;
    CMTime cmTime = CMTimeMake(longDuration, 1);
    [writer endSessionAtSourceTime:cmTime];

    [writer finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
        // Call delegate method here
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);    
}

#pragma mark - Private -

- (void)appendCMSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)bufferRef {
    if(![writerInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {
        NSLog(@"WriterInput not ready! status = %ld, error=%@", (long)writer.status, writer.error);
        return;
    }    
    BOOL success = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)bufferRef withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(frameCount++, (int32_t) framesPerSecond)];
    if(success == NO) {
        NSLog(@"Append buffer failed! status = %ld, error=%@", (long)writer.status, writer.error);  // Always gets here
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: I tested in iOS12, and crashed in `[writer startWriting]`.
I think it's not allowed to encode image in Extension.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this behavior on iOS 13.7 (17H35)

It seems that `AVAssetWriter` requires Foreground Privileges, which the extension doesn't have. ([source](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/84479))

The `startWriting` method returns `false` and `assetWriter.error` equals:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={
    NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-17508),
    NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed,
    NSUnderlyingError=0x282a80120 {
        Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-17508 "(null)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 14: no problem when using AVAssetWriter from BroadcastUpload extension [Example project with Package](https://github.com/romiroma/BroadcastWriter)